# custom dropdown slide up if I interact into jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The issue here is, the div that has a class of `filter_sub` (the custom menu dropdown) is sliding up (hide thing when click anywhere other than this element and its descendants) when I interact into the jquery ui date picker.

Any ideas, clues, help, suggestions, recommendations to fix my issue?

I want the custom menu dropdown (the one that has a class of `filter_sub`) to not slide up when I interact into the `jquery ui date picker` or to be sharpen other that `jquery ui datepicker` and the custom dropdown menu, when click anywhere then the jquery ui date picker will be hidden as well as the custom dropdown menu will slide up (hide).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thehide").hide();
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        });
       //when authorized person clicks on the attendance menu
        $(".filter_pages").unbind().click(function(e){
              $(this).next(".filter_sub").slideToggle();
              e.preventDefault();
          });


        $(document).mouseup(function(e)
          {
              var container = $(".filter_sub");
              var calendar = $(".ui-datepicker");

              if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
&& container.has(e.target).length === 0)  // ... nor a descendant of the container
              {

                      container.slideUp();

              }
          });
  
});
```

```css
.filter .filter_has_sub{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
.filter_pages{
    display: table;
    font: normal 12px 'mpregular', san-serif;
    padding: 7px;
    color: #7e7e7e;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
.filter_pages span, .filter_sub a span{
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.filter_pages span:first-child, .filter_sub a span:first-child{
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.filter_pages span:last-child{
    font-size: 8px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.filter_has_sub:first-child .filter_sub{
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 170px;
}
.filter_has_sub:first-child .filter_sub .filter_datepicker{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: table;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
.filter_has_sub:first-child .filter_sub .filter_datepicker span{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    color: #7e7e7e;
}
.filter_has_sub:first-child .filter_sub .datepicker{
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
}

.filter_sub{
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999999;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.filter_sub a{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font: normal 14px 'mplight', sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.filter_sub a:hover{
    color: #555;
}
.thehide{dsiplay: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter_has_sub extend data_filter" style="display: table; margin: 0px auto;">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default filter_pages"><span>Filter Data</span><span class="ion-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <div class="filter_sub thehide" id="pagesfilter">
                            <div class="extend clear" style="height: 5px;"></div>
                            <div class="filter_datepicker extend clear">
                                <span class="ion-calendar"></span><input class="form-control datepicker extend" name="from_what_date" placeholder="From what date" required/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="filter_datepicker extend clear">
                                <span class="ion-calendar"></span><input class="form-control datepicker extend" name="to_what_date" placeholder="To what date" required/>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-default center display_table" id="date_filter_button">Go</button>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are almost there. Here is what you can do:

- In your **`if`** clause inside **`mouseup`** function, add another
  condition: **`calendar.has(e.target).length===0`**. Which does the
  same thing as the other similar condition i.e. to make sure that the
  current **`target`** is not a descendant of the **`ui-datepicker`**
  element.
- Also, I noticed that your **`slideToggle`** inside **`click`** event and your **`slideUp`** inside your **`mouseup`** event were executing one after another if you clicked on **`filter_has_sub`** element to hide the inner elements. Easy fix is to add a **`stop(true)`** right before *sliding* to both **`slideToggle`** and **`slideUp`** calls.

***JS:***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".thehide").hide();
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
    $(".filter_pages").unbind().click(function (e) {
        $(this).next(".filter_sub").stop(true).slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $(".filter_sub");
        var calendar = $(".ui-datepicker");
        if (!container.is(e.target) && calendar.has(e.target).length === 0 && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            container.stop(true).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, works like charm, anyway whats that stop(true) do?

Comment: [Stops any running animation on selected element](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) while optionally [removing queued animations and/or jumping to the end of an animation](https://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd).

Answer (score 0):

The Menu already has `toggle` enabled, so no problem. So if All you have to do to is to check is if `nodeName` is HTML if the user clicks outside the target let it be `UI calender` or the `input box` of the slide

So, You dont have to check for `container.is(e.target)`

This is how you can do it ==> `(event.target.nodeName === 'HTML')`

check out the **[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tfo9smdw/)**

For more info Look into the **[jQuery Docs- event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)**